# Unable to Reset Heroku Shared Database

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I'm trying to reset my shared database on Heroku.

I've tried the following commands:

```
heroku pg:reset DATABASE
heroku pg:reset SHARED_DATABASE
heroku pg:reset SHARED_DATABASE_URL
heroku pg:reset DATABASE_URL
```

Every time I receive the error "Resource not found" despite these being in my environment vars (heroku config) and working with my application.

Anyone know what I could be doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: You can just do so from the website just click on this url https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/THENAMEOFYOURAPP/resources then click on whatever database you have (for example Heroku Postgres :: Database) then click on settings then reset database.

Comment: You can then run rake db:migrate from the Heroku rails console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just got this feedback from Heroku support:

> Hi, this is due to a bug in the heroku client. An updated release should be out later today >or monday.
>
> You may want to instead take this opportunity to try out the new dev databases: 
>   https://postgres.heroku.com/blog/past/2012/4/26/heroku_postgres_development_plan/
>
> June 08, 2012 09:47

Looks like you have to wait around or use the dev databases.